# Is there anything we can do on iOS to stay safe while waiting for Apple to issue an update for the latest FREAK SSL vulnerability?

Tags: ios, security, ssl

I guess [the vulnerability has been around for a decade](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/03/freak-flaw-in-android-and-apple-devices-cripples-https-crypto-protection/) [ars technica], but should we just stay away from using any personal information until there is a security patch?

Answer (score 1):

Use Chrome for the moment. IIRC, Mac Firefox (and Chrome) uses a vulnerable crypto library, but Google has promised a fix for Mac Chrome is imminent. 
See [this site](http://freakattack.com) for a table of vulnerable and safe browsers.

Comment: The question is about iOS :-)

Comment: I know the question is about iOS however to comment on Firefox, I just tested it with Firefox 36 under OS X10.8.5  against FREAK at [Tracking the FREAK Attack](https://freakattack.com/) and it's fine.  It reported "Good News! Your browser appears to be safe from the FREAK attack."